# wp_nav_menu add <span></span> tags inside <a></a> tags that is parent

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I found examples adding a class to top level items, so we can display an arrow in menu items with sub-items, but is seems terrible to cope with the already built in WordPress classes, can't display the arrow with current and CSS hover, it just ruins all states.

The current nav menu is like this `<li><a>Text</a></li>`

Is there someway to add a `<span class="arrow"></span>` within the parent `<a></a>` tags instead?!

Add -> "`<span class="arrow"></span>`" -> inside `<a/></a>` tags

Thus -> `<li><a>Text<span class="arrow"></span></li></a>` that is parent.

the current code Adds the `<span></span>` tags outside the `<a></a>` tags

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if('primary' == $args->theme_location && $depth ==0){
            $output .='<span class="arrow"></span>';
        }
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: would you like to consider jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the incorrect method. You need the `start_el` instead. Here is the code for it:

```
class add_span_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

        if ( 'primary' == $args->theme_location ) {
            $submenus = 0 == $depth || 1 == $depth ? get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'value' => $item->ID, 'fields' => 'ids' ) ) ) ) : false;
            $item_output .= ! empty( $submenus ) ? ( 0 == $depth ? '<span class="arrow"></span>' : '<span class="sub-arrow"></span>' ) : '';
        }
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

This code will add a `<span class="sub-arrow"></span>` to top-level menu items from the menu selected for the `primary` theme location in case that this menu item has any child items.

Comment: hey thanks nikola, I totally need it to be like is has parent then $item_output the following, can it be done please???? :)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't really understand what you meant :) I thought that you initially wanted to just add `<span class="arrow"></span>` inside of the `a` tag. Can you try to explain(with an example would be best) again what you want :)

Comment: if has parent or if has sub-menu then it outputs the following code, what would i add, what do you suggest?

Comment: would i add this at the top?    **if($depth > 0)
           return parent::end_lvl(&$output, $depth);**

Comment: Okay, I edited the code from my answer - it tries to pull a child menu of the current menu item and will add the spam only if: 1) this menu is the "primary" theme location menu AND 2) this is a top-level menu item AND 3) there are sub-menu items for this item. Please try the code and see if it works. If it doesn't I'll be able to reply tomorrow though, since I'm going to bed now :) Hope it works.

Comment: and it would be even awesomer if you can add another output if it sub-menu li has a sub-menu :)

Comment: Sure, do you want to have the same span in second-level menus? Maybe we can just make it to have a span as long as it has a sub-menu, regardless of the depth of the item. This way you won't have to worry about if you decide to add another level of sub-menus :)

Comment: Can you try again? This time a top-level item with sub-menus will get a span with class `arrow` and a second-level item with sub-menus will get a span with class `sub-arrow`.