# Picture to nav menu in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, image, nav

I would ask you for help because I could not find solve of this problem too long time.

Is some simple possible way hot to replace text in wordpress menu by some icon just with css? I need insert picture in main menu of http://www.monetaria.cz . I tried to use class in specification of menu items and for erase text I used text-indent bud it did this problem

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/idGdXrE_x3LLDWvJQ-doyKHTNTSbdw6n6xqWnRyE6B8?feat=directlink

Thank you very much,

John

Comment: I would recommend writing a custom Menu walker which will add a `<span class="icon"></span>` element in your top-level menu items. You can then add a custom class(from Appearance > Menus in the WordPress dashboard) to each element and style the `span.icon` correspondingly. You can see an example code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394810/wp-nav-menu-add-span-span-tags-inside-a-a-tags-that-is-parent/13395250#13395250) - it's not perfectly suited for your needs, but it shouldn't be hard to modify it to your needs.

Comment: You could simply do `text-indent:-9999` to push the text off the screen, then target each element and provide it an image. You can do a background image with CSS, or use jQuery to insert images. Creating a walker for this seems a bit too much.

Comment: Ohgodwhy:Thank you very much for your reply, I have used text-indent: -9999 but that is what I showed in picture what that did and why I can not use this way solving problem

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov  Thank you very much for your reply, I have looked on that but, I have used this way, when I defined class in Appearance > Menus and next I defined background in css but it still not function I will show you my css:  .ico {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(images/envelope_icon.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    width: 50px;
}

Answer (score 0):

you can add HTML straight into a menu item and WP will render it properly, so if you add something like this

```
<img src="source.jpg" />
```

into the `Label` field of a Custom Link and enter whatever link you want the menu item to go to into the `URL` field, then WP will render the `<img>` tag as an image and also wrap it in a link to your specified URL